# how to use aria attributes in binding.scala

Tags: html, scala, wai-aria, scala.js, binding.scala

How can i use [aria attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) in Binding.scala?

When compiling the following:

```
 <div role="option" aria-checked="false"/>
```

the following error gets displayed:

`value aria-checked is not a member of org.scalajs.dom.html.Div`

fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/75Dqnso/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All properties defined in scala-js-dom is automatically available for XHTML literals in Binding.scala.

However, such `aria-checked` property has not been defined in current version of scala-js-dom.
You can use [custom attributes](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala#custom-attributes) as a workaround:

```
<div data:role="option" data:aria-checked="false"></div>
```